# Swift (SwiftUI) programming syntax operator meaning?

Tags: swift

I don't know how to word the question to find help in a search engine. Basically I'm trying to figure out the meaning of this operation

`self.isFromCurrentUser = fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`

The variables are NOT the question because I already know about Firebase and whatnot. Rather the question is why is there an assignment operator `=` and an `==` in this line of code?

`variable1 = variable2 == variable3`

What does this mean? What is variable1 getting assigned to?

Comment: Also, the people voting to close for "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." should recognize that these "multiple questions" are the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```swift
variable1 = variable2 == variable
```

assigns `variable1` the value of the boolean (true or false) of the result of `variable2 == variable3` (if they are equal).

It's equivalent to

```swift
if variable2 == variable3 {
  variable1 = true
} else {
  variable1 = false
}
```